# Bootstrap set active tab with request.path_parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ruby on rails application which includes a header-file on every page.

Now i want to set the active pathes.

```
<li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(users_path) %> dropdown">test</li>
```

This works without trouble.

Now i have a page for create a new user => `users/new`. So i tried around with `request.path_parameters`

```
<% if ((request.path_parameters[:controller] == "users") && (request.path_parameters[:action] == "new")) %>
    <li class="active dropdown">test</li> 
<% end %>
```

The problem is that the if-condition is always `true`.
I can change it to:

```
<% if ((request.path_parameters[:controller] == "userstest") && (request.path_parameters[:action] == "newtest")) %>
    <li class="active dropdown">test</li> 
<% end %>
```

and its still true.

Anybody know a solutions for this?

When i try:

```
current_page?(url_for(:controller => 'users', :action => 'new'))
```

i get a `No route matches`-error

Comment: why can't you use a your helper method for users/new too? something like: `<li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(your_path_for_new_action) %> dropdown">test</li>`. Your paths can't be same and i don't think you'll require your post method like create or destroy with delete method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use == instead of =

`<% if ((request.path_parameters[:controller] == "users") && (request.path_parameters[:action] == "new")) %>
    <li class="active dropdown">test</li> 
<% end %>`

There are also helper methods available to get the controller and action.

`controller_name` and 
`action_name`

Comment: Soory for this question. Thanks! My bad. Sitting to long in front of this code.